# How can CruiseControl.NET realize that it can control remote pc to execute automation test and monitor the status?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to realize that CCNET can control remote pc to execute a bat file which is in file server and monitor the status,stop or finished.
the bat file is CodeUI automation test.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but what I am assuming that you are trying to do is to have CruiseControl execute a shell command.

Check out

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task

So something like this in your script

<exec executable="\\server\c$\projects\myproject\build.bat" />

If however that bat file must be run from the computer the script is located try looking in psexec.exe.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

https://superuser.com/questions/781796/run-a-batch-file-on-a-remote-computer-as-administrator

Comment: Thank for your answer.I will use pstool to solve it.

Comment: But I try psexec with the command line,it is hang:   Psexec \\jessica-win7x64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\winword.exe"; can you help me?

Comment: Hmmm why are you trying to run Microsoft Word? I thought you were trying to run a bat file?

Comment: I try to use the command line to execute the bat file,but it hang. the bat is to execute code UI ,it related to the ui interaction